# Can I modify the run  method of main thread

Tags: java

I am curious to know if it is possible to modify the run method of main thread like in other threads we override the run method and define the desired behaviour.

Also may I know if the code we write in main method actually gets added to the run method of main thread coz this is what gets executed when the main thread runs.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It might help if you give an example of what this "run of main thread" does and how you would want to modify it

Comment: For guidance, see [ask].

Comment: What do you mean? You can create new threads passing in a runnable object. Each runnable can have whatever you want in

Comment: @MiserableVariableI mean to say since main is a thread and must be having a run method of its own to make the thread running, can we modify its run method so as to control its behaviour .

Comment: I think you would get more traction if you clearly described the problem you have, as what you ask in your question seems more like a possible solution you've settled upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the main method is not used during the whole application life. You just use it to initialize and run other threads and then let it terminate:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new firstThreadImplementation().start();
    // new secondThreadImplementation().start();
    new initGuiThread().start();
    // we are finished here and don't need this thread anymore
  }
}
```

So you can directly control the `run()` method of the started threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't override the thread used to execute your `main()` method. This thread comes into existence through JVM magic, and its `run()` method is never called (to be more accurate, its `start()` method is never called; you can see a note to that effect in the source). It simply exists to maintain a regular threading model (ie, every thread can call `Thread.currentThread()` and get something back).